# new Date returning invalid Date safari

Tags: javascript, date, ecmascript-6, safari, invalidation

Hope all of you are doing fine. I stumbled across a problem in **SAFARI**. If I have a date like this

`2016-05-31T10:00:00`

and apply this function to the date

`new Date(2016-05-31T10:00:00)`

it returns me a proper result

`Thu Mar 31 2016 10:00:00 GMT+0500 (PKT)`

but if I add timezone offset to my date

`2016-05-31T10:00:00-0400`

and then apply the `new Date` function on it, it starts throwing an `invalid date` error. Can somebody tell me why is this happening and whats the way to resolve this problem

Comment: Read the [note on the `dateString` parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters).

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli thanks for the link. Can you  suggest a way to resolve this problem

Comment: You could use `Date.UTC` but you need to split your date accordingly, or you can use the moment.js library to do the parsing, which supports the format you have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that [*ECMA-262*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-date-time-string-format) defines the timezone component as being ±HH:mm, so "-0400" is missing the separating colon.

Since the string is not compliant with the standard, the parser has the option of applying its own logic, or returning an invalid Date. Safari applies the latter logic.

The general advice is to not use the built-in parser and either use a library or to implement your own parser for your particular format (not difficult, only 4 or 5 lines of code).